# formatter:'select' does not display the description of the element but rather the value of the option

Tags: free-jqgrid

Using free JqGrid, I am loading the editOptions via a jquery ajax call, I also have a jsonMap for the element, now when using formatter:'select', it does not display the description of the option but rather the value

I have already tried building the formatter, the drop down shows up but does not have the selected value

{

```
                    name:'position_code',
                    index:'position_code',
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype:'text',
                    width:200,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype:"select",
                    editoptions:{
                        value: function(){ 
                            return buildDropDown(drpPosition,"");
                        }

                    },
                    formatter:'Select',
                    /* 
                     formatter:function(){ 
                            return "<SELECT>"+buildOptions(drpPosition,"")+"</SELECT>";
                    }, 
                    formatoptions: {disabled : false}, */

                    jsonmap:function(row){
                                return row["position_code"].val;
                    }
                },
```

So let us say the values of buildDropDown(drpPosition,""); returns "1:one,2:two,3:three" etc

and the value of the row["position_code"].val = 2

I expect it to show two on the grid but it shows 2

Comment: @Oleg can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The code in JavaScript is case sensitive.
You have put in code

```
formatter : 'Select',
```

which is not correct. It should be:

```
formatter : 'select',
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: I am thinking the problem is because of edit options being fetched through an ajax call, that the formatter does not know what to do OR because the json map is present

Comment: could you also please help me with this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/56971942/11616158?sem=2

Comment: could you also please help me with this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/56971942/11616158?sem=2